# Entity Framework Power Tools - missing Table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I'm coding a Web-Api application and I used "Entity Framework Power Tool" to generate my model classes.
But there are some missing tables. I miss all tables for many to many relationships.

Is there a way to generate model classes for all entities?

Comment: Did you get list with check boxes with all tables in the wizard?

Comment: Are you doing tests with the AdventuresWorks? Because have a bug with this schema and Power Tools. The version beta 3 of Power Tools is, like the name, BETA and still have bugs... I'm sorry about it

Comment: No there was no check boxes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620 Only windows like the pictures in my link

Comment: I didn't know AdventuresWorks before your post. But I can't change the  DB. So i need to find a solution with the current DB